# Possible to hide admin menu if custom module is disabled?

Tags: module, magento-1, navigation

I am working on a custom backend module that has an option in *System > Configuration* to enable or disable the module.

[image: System > Configuration]

I would like to know if it is possible to hide the navigation item from the admin dashboard if the module is disabled?

[image: Admin Dashboard]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a good article by Ecomdev that gives an example of how you can do this with the 'depends' functionality. Search for 'depends' on that page and it will demonstrate how to use a config value. e.g.

```
<depends>
    <config>payment/checkmo/active</config>
</depends>
```

The menu item will only show if the check payment method is active.

http://www.ecomdev.org/2010/10/28/defining-acl-resources-custom-and-admin-menu-in-magento.html

Comment: This worked perfectly, although there was an error.

Should have read <config> instead of <module>

Comment: Edited, and glad it worked :)

Comment: Mind that this does only work for child entries and not for top-level menu entries.

Comment: perfect!!! +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

The `adminhtml.xml` and the `config.xml` are both loaded into the configuration xml (`Mage::getSingleton('admin/config')->getAdminhtmlConfig()`), so yes sure it is possible.

```
app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Config.php:59
Mage::getConfig()->loadModulesConfiguration('adminhtml.xml', $adminhtmlConfig);
```

I think you have two options, either disable the menu in ACL.

```
Mage::getConfig()->loadModulesConfiguration('adminhtml.xml', $adminhtmlConfig);
```

or unset the node directly in the config. See `\Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Page_Menu::_buildMenuArray`

But I think both is not possible at the moment with the API `Mage_Admin_Model_Config` offers, so you maybe need to rewrite `Mage_Admin_Model_Config`