# How to hide a admin menu based on config value for enable or disable for custom module in magento?

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, module, menu, system.xml

Is there any possibility to hide a menu related to a custom module in the admin side when the custom module is deactivated using the system config options written in the system.xml of the magento.

Please anyone help me.

Comment: duplicate of : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10176/possible-to-hide-admin-menu-if-custom-module-is-disabled

Comment: please tell me where to add the <depends> tab to hide my menu.Menu is defined in adminhtml.xml file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in comments to OP question, this is a duplicate of [Possible to hide admin menu if custom module is disabled?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10176/possible-to-hide-admin-menu-if-custom-module-is-disabled)

but placed as answer to respond to OP's comments.

You will place the `<depends>` in the menu item configuration, as such:

(code example taken from ecomdev's post mentioned in the noted duplicate answer)

```
     <menu>
        <mycustom_menu translate="title" module="[module_name]">
            <!-- this depends will hide the entire menu option -->
            <depends>
              <config>payment/checkmo/active</config>
            </depends>
            <title>My Custom Menu Item</title>
            <sort_order>300</sort_order>
            <children>
                <!-- child items go here -->
                <subitem translate="title" module="[module_name]">
                    <!-- this depends will hide the sub menu option -->
                    <depends>
                       <module>payment/checkmo/active</module>
                    </depends>
                    <title>Subitem</title>
                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/mycustom_controller/</action>
                </subitem>
            </children>
        </mycustom_menu>
    </menu>
```

Comment: but this is not worked for me

Comment: can you add your actual code to the question please

Comment: when i replace the <module> by<config> and place the config value its worked for me....

Comment: Great, my bad cut and paste, sorry